# How to show data in a tableView with Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can anyone try to explain the steps I need to do? I get a lot of errors when I try to define my database in Xcode.

```
dbRef.child("class").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: 
{ (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot().value? as? [String: AnyObject]

        let description = value? ["desciption"] as? [Any]
        let owner = value? ["owner"] as? [Any]
        let participant = value? ["participant"] as? [Any]
        let time = value? ["time"] as? [Any]

        print("description: \(String(describing: description))")
        print("owner: \(String(describing: owner))")
        print("participant: \(String(describing: participant))")
        print("time: \(String(describing: time))")
```

Comment: The error is Cannot call value of non-function type 'DataSnapshot'

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the () on `snapshot().value`. Make it `snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]` and that will remove the error "Cannot call value of non-function type 'DataSnapshot'"

Basically the error can be taken literally. snapshot (which is type DataSnapshot) is not a function, so you can't call it as a function i.e snapshot()